# react-native could not get BundleBridge on android virtual device

Tags: android, react-native

I was following https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html .My development OS - macOS , mobile - android.
I can succesfully start an app on real android device, but not on virtual device.

When I'm trying to run it on AVD, I have no errors in the console and packager starts correctly:

```
$react-native run-android
...
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus_5X_API_23_x86(AVD) - 6.0' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 10.303 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Running /Users/ignat/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on emulator-5554 (/Users/ignat/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.three/.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.three/.MainActivity }
```

But on virtual device I get this error:
[image: 1]

If I Reload device, then I get this:

[image: 2]

I have latest android studio and JDK, I did every step as in guide. ADB works. Nothing from related questions helped, most of them are related to the real device and I don't have stacktrace in the first image.
Any help?

Comment: Did you try running $ `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` and then trying again?

Comment: tried,  doesn't work

Comment: You need to setup your "Dev Settings". Dev Settings > Debug server host & port for device and put your IP address + the port where your application is running. e.g "192.168.1.2:8081" and reload your application.

Comment: @seanarce tried this one too, no result

Comment: @Kaign Weird. This error always shows when I haven't connected my virtual device on the port where the application is running. Do you get new errors after you setup the Dev Settings?

Comment: @seanarce all the same, by "reload application" you mean executing `react-native run-android` again? I get same error..

Comment: @Kaign No there is a reload button on dev settings that you can use to reload the app without doing "react-native run-android".

Comment: @seanarce same error :(

Comment: @Kaign Ow okay you need to run the following "react-native start" and reload the app. Sorry didn't notice this earlier could have saved you time, anyway I hope this fixes your issue :)

Comment: @seanarce thanks, but this is not the case either :)

Comment: @Kaign did "react-native start" fix the issue?

Comment: @seanarce no, packager works correctly